# C# Facebook sdk: posting on page on owner's behalf

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I have a page on facebook and i want to get my page access token so that i could use it to post ob my page from a mobile application or web application using the facebook sdk for C#.

I think the whole idea would be:

- user will go to my webpage.
- user will then login to facebook.
- user will be taken back to my page with the his page's access token.
- i will save this access token and then use it to post on his page on his behalf.

Right now i am not sure whether these are the right steps or not and if i am right, how can i make a facebook login page where user can use?

EDIT:

I found some answer here: [Programatically log in to facebook and post from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544963/programatically-log-in-to-facebook-and-post-from-server-side)

do i need to create a facebook app for that?